# insert tables in dataframe with years from 2000 to 20018 with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I created a column 'Year' I want to insert year in the dataframe every 13 rows from 2000 to 2018. `pd.concat()` did not work for me

|  | Coastal_Fisheries | Small_Pelagic | Clam_Harvesting | Total_Catches | Month | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 63299 | No Data | 20301 | 83600 | 1 | 0.0 |
| 2 | 41999 | 29854 | 21404 | 93257 | 2 | 0.0 |
| 3 | 41028 | No Data | 4179 | 45207 | 3 | 0.0 |
| 4 | 35812 | No Data | 2132 | 37944 | 4 | 0.0 |
| 5 | 70262 | 13156 | 81882 | 165300 | 5 | 0.0 |
| 6 | 46519 | 5940 | No Data | 52459 | 6 | 0.0 |
| 7 | 43317 | 7981 | No Data | 51298 | 7 | 0.0 |
| 8 | 55803 | 12219 | No Data | 68022 | 8 | 0.0 |
| 9 | 44737 | 15772 | No Data | 60509 | 9 | 0.0 |
| 10 | 35031 | 6233 | No Data | 41264 | 10 | 0.0 |
| 11 | 86585 | 33925 | 116176 | 236686 | 11 | 0.0 |
| 12 | 62267 | 13340 | 204554 | 280161 | 12 | 0.0 |
| 13 | 626660 | 138420 | 450628 | 1215708 | None | 0.0 |
| 1 | 60918 | 143509 | 60575 | 265002 | 1 | 0.0 |

Comment: post the data in text format

Comment: Why is the index starting from 1 again? Why are there 13 months? And what exactly have you tried to do with concat()?

Comment: I created other dataframe df with 'year' column to concat it with the original, but it did not work. df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [year for year in range(2000, 2018)]})
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(13)]

Comment: Your index will be 1 again or 14??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `index` is from `0 to n`:

You can `groupby` by taking 13 consecutive index and assign them year

```
df['Year'] = df.groupby((df.index)//13).ngroup().add(2000)
```

If your index is as mentioned in the post then `groupby` consecutive index.

```
df['Year']  = df.groupby(df.index.to_series().diff().ne(1).cumsum()).ngroup().add(2000)
```

|  | Coastal_Fisheries | Small_Pelagic | Clam_Harvesting | Total_Catches | Month | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 41999 | 29854.0 | 21404.0 | 93257 | 2 | 2000 |
| 2 | 41028 | NaN | 4179.0 | 45207 | 3 | 2000 |
| 3 | 35812 | NaN | 2132.0 | 37944 | 4 | 2000 |
| 4 | 70262 | 13156.0 | 81882.0 | 165300 | 5 | 2000 |
| 5 | 46519 | 5940.0 | NaN | 52459 | 6 | 2000 |
| 6 | 43317 | 7981.0 | NaN | 51298 | 7 | 2000 |
| 7 | 55803 | 12219.0 | NaN | 68022 | 8 | 2000 |
| 8 | 44737 | 15772.0 | NaN | 60509 | 9 | 2000 |
| 9 | 35031 | 6233.0 | NaN | 41264 | 10 | 2000 |
| 10 | 86585 | 33925.0 | 116176.0 | 236686 | 11 | 2000 |
| 11 | 62267 | 13340.0 | 204554.0 | 280161 | 12 | 2000 |
| 12 | 626660 | 138420.0 | 450628.0 | 1215708 | None | 2000 |
| 13 | 60918 | 143509.0 | 60575.0 | 265002 | 1 | 2000 |
| 1 | 41999 | 29854.0 | 21404.0 | 93257 | 2 | 2001 |
| 2 | 41028 | NaN | 4179.0 | 45207 | 3 | 2001 |
| 3 | 35812 | NaN | 2132.0 | 37944 | 4 | 2001 |
| 4 | 70262 | 13156.0 | 81882.0 | 165300 | 5 | 2001 |
| 5 | 46519 | 5940.0 | NaN | 52459 | 6 | 2001 |
| 6 | 43317 | 7981.0 | NaN | 51298 | 7 | 2001 |
| 7 | 55803 | 12219.0 | NaN | 68022 | 8 | 2001 |
| 8 | 44737 | 15772.0 | NaN | 60509 | 9 | 2001 |
| 9 | 35031 | 6233.0 | NaN | 41264 | 10 | 2001 |
| 10 | 86585 | 33925.0 | 116176.0 | 236686 | 11 | 2001 |
| 11 | 62267 | 13340.0 | 204554.0 | 280161 | 12 | 2001 |
| 12 | 626660 | 138420.0 | 450628.0 | 1215708 | None | 2001 |
| 13 | 60918 | 143509.0 | 60575.0 | 265002 | 1 | 2001 |
| 1 | 63299 | NaN | 20301.0 | 83600 | 1 | 2002 |

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is to create an array of values from 2000 to 2xxx with a step number of 13 of the same length as the number of row indexes of the dataframe. Then Insert this array to dataframe.

---

*For example:*

As below, I manually create a dataframe with step number = 13 and number of row = 15.

```
    import pandas as pd
    
    id = 13 # The step number
    # The dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Total": [i for i in range(15)], 
                        "months": [i for i in range(1,id)]+['None',1,2]
                      }, index=[i for i in range(1,id+1)]+[1,2])
    # Create data of 'Year' column
    lst = len(df.index)
    i_lst = round(lst/id)
    df2 = [id*[2000+i] for i in range(i_lst)][0] + lst%id*[i_lst+2000]
    # result df2 = [2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001]
    
    # Insert 'Year' column
    df.insert(loc=2, column='Year', value=df2)
```

The results will be:

```
    Total months  Year
1       0      1  2000
2       1      2  2000
3       2      3  2000
4       3      4  2000
5       4      5  2000
6       5      6  2000
7       6      7  2000
8       7      8  2000
9       8      9  2000
10      9     10  2000
11     10     11  2000
12     11     12  2000
13     12   None  2000
1      13      1  2001
2      14      2  2001
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the code you posted in the comment above:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [year for year in range(2000, 2018)]}) 
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(13)]
```

then you are probably experiencing a indexing error, and you need to reset the indexes of both your original dataframe (which I'm calling `data`) and your "Year" dataframe:

```
data = data.reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

and at this point `pd.concat()` should work:

```
df2 = pd.concat([data,df], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, this also working